# http request like others, but which doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, http

I'm trying to get a website's content into a String. I searched for long on this website and others to find an example, but none worked.

I took the code from a tutorial video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxcfhAU2dDg

I added the permission, 3G is working (other app access to internet and the icon is shown).

I also tried on a real device, but without positive results.

I've probably just made a stupid mistake.  Can you help me to find my bug, please.

My code is:

```
package com.example.testfail;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView httpStuff;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    GetMethodEx test = new GetMethodEx();
    String returned;
    try {
        returned = test.getInternetData();
        httpStuff.setText(returned);
        httpStuff.setText("ah?");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

and the GetMethodEx:

```
package com.example.testfail;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class GetMethodEx {

public String getInternetData() throws Exception{

    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("google.com");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while((l = in.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(l + nl);
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
        return data;
    } finally {
        if(in != null){
            try {
                in.close();
                return data;
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the error here? If any error Post your logcat also

Comment: i hope u r getting some kind of exception and u have to use AsynkTask to do this because with UI thread u cannot do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do network tasks on the UI thread. This is not allowed. You must do the network requests in a separate thread i.e extend AsyncTask

I will post the code, only because it is a tutorial and I happened to look at this myself some time ago. You can see that AsyncTask is used:

```
public class HTTPGetter extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView tvHttp;
BufferedReader in = null;
EditText ethttp;
Button bhttp;
String returned, strhttp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.httpex);
    tvHttp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHTTP);
    bhttp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bhttp);
    ethttp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ethttp);
    bhttp.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private class HTTPGet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    BufferedReader in = null;
    String returned = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            URI website = new URI(strhttp);

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

            request.setURI(website);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                    .getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");

            String l = "";

            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(l + nl);
            }

            in.close();
            returned = sb.toString();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tvHttp.setText(returned);
    }
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bhttp:

        strhttp = ethttp.getText().toString();
        HTTPGet test = new HTTPGet();

        try {
            test.execute(strhttp);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it returns me a white fied

Comment: It works I've just tested it again. Make sure you have 
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Also make sure the name of the class matches the activity name in your manifest. For example you may need to change the class name HTTPGetter back to MainActivity. Also make sure the url has http:// before the address that you are requesting..
Also make sure all your references to your xml layout are correct and your setting the correct xml file as your content view. I really can't help any more than that been as I'm running the app right now!

Comment: yes, it's done. I don't understand why it becomes white. I believe you if you say it's working, but on my side, not. when i click, the text field empties it, so it's probably an empty the returned value which is not correct. maybe give me a link witch works (I already tried many)... I'm hopeless :/